# Handsontable renders off screen

Tags: html, css, handsontable

I am using the demo code for [handsontable](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.24.1/tutorial-quick-start.html) plugin.

The code is:

```
var data = [
  ["", "Ford", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Honda"],
  ["2016", 10, 11, 12, 13],
  ["2017", 20, 11, 14, 13],
  ["2018", 30, 15, 12, 13]
];

var container = document.getElementById('example');
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: data,
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: true
});
```

My div is: `<div id="example"></div>`.

But when it renders the plugin, it is off the screen.

[image: full screen]

[image: off-screen]

I have figured out that it is an issue with the CSS. But it is the stock standard CSS?

If I change:

```
.ht_master .wtHolder {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

to:

```
.ht_master .wtHolder {
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Then it bring the content inline, in terms of:

[image]

But then the blocks are not in the correct position. Any tips on the styling?

Comment: Its better to fiddle your code for quick answers.